# Expression conversion (step by step)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What algebraic rules can be applied to convert from

$\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n+1+n$

To

$\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)+1$

This equivalence was presented in the textbook Concrete Mathematics to prove the closed form of a recurrence for determining the maximum number of regions defined by n lines in the plane. I haven't used algebra for some time, so I've been trying to re-learn the basics using the Khan Academy site along with other sources, but I'm having trouble seeing what is probably a simple conversion and could use some assistance to get me in the right direction.

Comment: I agree it's a very specific question. I was having trouble seeing the steps and just needed some guidance to feel comfortable with how the conversion could be done. The first step that angryavian showed below really cleared it up for me. I just did not see that grouping and distribution when looking for the correct steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} (n-1) n + 1 + n
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} (n-1) + 1\right)n + 1 & \text{distributive prop.}\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}n - \frac{1}{2} + 1\right)n + 1\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{2}\right)n + 1\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(n+1)n + 1\\
\end{align}